# Young Double Slit Experiment Formula - Nodal Lines

Tags: visible-light, waves, double-slit-experiment

Some sources use the formula $\frac{X_n}{L}= (\frac{(n-\frac{1}{2})λ}{d})$, while other sources use $\frac{X_n}{L}= (\frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})λ}{d})$ when talking about destructive interference. 
Why is there a discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without definition of all variables, both formulas don't mean anything.

One possible explanation for the difference is that one starts counting $n$ from 0 while the other one starts from 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no discrepancy as the interference pattern is symmetrical.  The relationship for constructive interference contains the term $n\lambda$ and to find the positions for destructive interference one needs to change the path length by either $+\frac \lambda 2$ or  $-\frac \lambda 2$.